# `echo` (shell bash) sending integer values and not only chars and strings. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, char

### Question

`echo -n 1 > /dev/LED` writes the ASCII value of `1`, i.e. the char decimal value corresponding to `49`.
Ok, I can easily manage ASCII characters in the device driver but the question is:
can I send 'unsigned integer' with the `echo` function of the shell bash in Linux?
The goal will be to write the hexadecimal `0x01`

### Context

I don't think is important but I am trying to send integer to the `.write` function inside a Linux device driver. To manage ASCII it is easy as ever but I would like to keep the Kernel-code as simple as possible because it can impact on performance.

Comment: `echo` is the wrong tool for the job -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [its POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` just writes strings; if you want the string containing the character `0x01`, you'll have to specify that. You should use `printf`, though:

```
printf '\x01' > /dev/LED
```

This will work in `bash`, but other implementations of `printf` may not support hexadecimal escapes. Octal is the only standard supported:

```
printf '\001' > /dev/LED
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -en "\x01" > /dev/LED
```

The `-e` option tells `echo` to interpret escape sequences, and `-n` tells it to omit the trailing new line.

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable -- any version of `echo` that does anything but print `-e` on output when it's given is in active violation of the relevant POSIX standard; and bash's `echo` only violates that standard *sometimes* -- if both `xpg_echo` and `posix` runtime flags are active its behavior is compliant, and consequently this code doesn't work.

Comment: yes, I have used -n because I saw that it try to write the new line character!

Comment: (`-e` is an "active violation", as opposed to an extension, insofar as it violates the black-and-white language in the spec that "Implementations shall not support any options"; `-n` is a sole exception to that, insofar as it's defined as making `echo`'s behavior undefined by the standard when present -- but *undefined* behavior isn't a great thing to be using in your programs either).